# newAPIHadoopRDD reading from HBase consuming too much time (Main cause is Dns.reverseDns)

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, dns, hbase, apache-zookeeper

Recently, When I was testing my cluster with Spark and HBase. I was using newAPIHadoopRDD to read records from HBase table. I found that newAPIHadoopRDD was too slow, and the time was proportional to the number of Region Servers.

The spark debug(opened for test) logs below shows the procedure:

```
17/03/02 22:00:30 DEBUG AbstractRpcClient: Use SIMPLE authentication for service ClientService, sasl=false
17/03/02 22:00:30 DEBUG AbstractRpcClient: Connecting to slave111/192.168.10.111:16020
17/03/02 22:00:30 DEBUG ClientCnxn: Reading reply sessionid:0x15a8de8a86f0444, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 5,3  replyHeader:: 5,116079898,0  request:: '/hbase,F  response:: s{116070329,116070329,1488462020202,1488462020202,0,16,0,0,0,16,116070652} 
17/03/02 22:00:30 DEBUG ClientCnxn: Reading reply sessionid:0x15a8de8a86f0444, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 6,4  replyHeader:: 6,116079898,0  request:: '/hbase/master,F  response:: #ffffffff000146d61737465723a3136303030fffffff4ffffffa23affffffc8ffffffb6ffffffb1ffffffc21a50425546a12a66d617374657210ffffff807d18ffffffcffffffff4fffffffffffffff9ffffffa82b10018ffffff8a7d,s{116070348,116070348,1488462021202,1488462021202,0,0,0,97546372339663909,54,0,116070348} 
17/03/02 22:00:30 DEBUG AbstractRpcClient: Use SIMPLE authentication for service MasterService, sasl=false
17/03/02 22:00:30 DEBUG AbstractRpcClient: Connecting to master/192.168.10.100:16000
17/03/02 22:00:30 DEBUG RegionSizeCalculator: Region tt,3,1488442069431.21d34666d310df3f180b2dba093d910d. has size 0
17/03/02 22:00:30 DEBUG RegionSizeCalculator: Region tt,,1488442069431.cb8696957957f824f1a16210768bf197. has size 0
17/03/02 22:00:30 DEBUG RegionSizeCalculator: Region tt,1,1488442069431.274ddaa4abb34f0408cac0f33107529c. has size 0
17/03/02 22:00:30 DEBUG RegionSizeCalculator: Region tt,2,1488442069431.05dd84aacb7f2587e325c8baf4c27613. has size 0
17/03/02 22:00:30 DEBUG RegionSizeCalculator: Region sizes calculated
17/03/02 22:00:38 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (480943798) connection to master/192.168.10.100:9000 from hadoop: closed
17/03/02 22:00:38 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (480943798) connection to master/192.168.10.100:9000 from hadoop: stopped, remaining connections 0
17/03/02 22:00:43 DEBUG ClientCnxn: Got ping response for sessionid: 0x15a8de8a86f0444 after 0ms
17/03/02 22:00:56 DEBUG ClientCnxn: Got ping response for sessionid: 0x15a8de8a86f0444 after 0ms
17/03/02 22:01:00 DEBUG TableInputFormatBase: getSplits: split -> 0 -> HBase table split(table name: tt, scan: , start row: , end row: 1, region location: slave104)
17/03/02 22:01:10 DEBUG ClientCnxn: Got ping response for sessionid: 0x15a8de8a86f0444 after 0ms
17/03/02 22:01:23 DEBUG ClientCnxn: Got ping response for sessionid: 0x15a8de8a86f0444 after 0ms
17/03/02 22:01:30 DEBUG TableInputFormatBase: getSplits: split -> 1 -> HBase table split(table name: tt, scan: , start row: 1, end row: 2, region location: slave102)
17/03/02 22:01:37 DEBUG ClientCnxn: Got ping response for sessionid: 0x15a8de8a86f0444 after 0ms
17/03/02 22:01:50 DEBUG ClientCnxn: Got ping response for sessionid: 0x15a8de8a86f0444 after 0ms
17/03/02 22:02:00 DEBUG TableInputFormatBase: getSplits: split -> 2 -> HBase table split(table name: tt, scan: , start row: 2, end row: 3, region location: slave112)
17/03/02 22:02:03 DEBUG ClientCnxn: Got ping response for sessionid: 0x15a8de8a86f0444 after 0ms
17/03/02 22:02:17 DEBUG ClientCnxn: Got ping response for sessionid: 0x15a8de8a86f0444 after 0ms
17/03/02 22:02:30 DEBUG ClientCnxn: Got ping response for sessionid: 0x15a8de8a86f0444 after 0ms
17/03/02 22:02:30 DEBUG TableInputFormatBase: getSplits: split -> 3 -> HBase table split(table name: tt, scan: , start row: 3, end row: , region location: slave108)
17/03/02 22:02:30 INFO ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closing master protocol: MasterService
17/03/02 22:02:30 INFO ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closing zookeeper sessionid=0x15a8de8a86f0444
17/03/02 22:02:30 DEBUG ZooKeeper: Closing session: 0x15a8de8a86f0444
17/03/02 22:02:30 DEBUG ClientCnxn: Closing client for session: 0x15a8de8a86f0444
17/03/02 22:02:30 DEBUG ClientCnxn: Reading reply sessionid:0x15a8de8a86f0444, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 7,-11  replyHeader:: 7,116080795,0  request:: null response:: null
17/03/02 22:02:30 DEBUG ClientCnxn: Disconnecting client for session: 0x15a8de8a86f0444
17/03/02 22:02:30 INFO ZooKeeper: Session: 0x15a8de8a86f0444 closed
17/03/02 22:02:30 INFO ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
17/03/02 22:02:30 DEBUG AbstractRpcClient: Stopping rpc client
17/03/02 22:02:30 DEBUG ClientCnxn: An exception was thrown while closing send thread for session 0x15a8de8a86f0444 : Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x15a8de8a86f0444, likely server has closed socket
17/03/02 22:02:30 DEBUG ClosureCleaner: +++ Cleaning closure <function1> (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1) +++
```

I'm using Spark 2.1.0, HBase 1.1.2. It took too much time for getSplits operation. The region server numbers was tested from one to four, and it took 30 seconds for each region server. HBase table contains no records (just for test).

Is this normal? and does anyone suffer the same problem as me?

The test code shows below:

```
Configuration hconf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
hconf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, GLOBAL.TABLE_NAME);
hconf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.10.100");
hconf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
Scan scan = new Scan();

JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> results
        = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(hconf, TableInputFormat.class, ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Result.class);

long cnt = results.count();
System.out.println(cnt);
```

**EDIT**

After debugging with HBase source code, I found the cause of the slow speed. The **reverse DNS** operation from **[TableInputFormatBase.java](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/branch-1.1/hbase-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableInputFormatBase.java#L350)** is the culprit.

```
ipAddressString = DNS.reverseDns(ipAddress, null);
```

How to solve this problem now? Can I add some dns-ip pair in HBase configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the result below when using nslookup to reverse find 192.168.10.100.

```
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

so, I executed the cmds below,

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.0/24 -o em4 -j MASQUERADE
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo route add default gw 'mygatway' em4
```

then, the problem is gone.